# Is there any way to automatically create graphql api documentation?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, graphql

I have only the **Introspection schema of a GraphQL api. I want to generate documentation for the graphql api to know the queries & mutations.**

*Except graphql voyager* is there any cli tool/ website available to **generate static  documentation site  from only the Introspection schema?**

I tried https://github.com/wayfair/dociql but for that tool we need to specify usecases and it was not automatically generating from the Introspection schema.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use https://github.com/anvilco/spectaql

I haven't tried it myself but it looks like in this [example](https://github.com/anvilco/spectaql/blob/main/examples/config.yml) the introspection of the schema is being loaded from a static file.